# CSS Span forcing page to be wider it should be

Tags: css, frontend

The error specifically is that the span element has a width of 900 pixels and it forces the page to scroll horizontally due to it extending so far at smaller screen sizes. I tried using the overflow: hidden property but that does not stop the scrolling.

The reason why I need 900 pixels is so my text and borders are centered and my border doesn't split into two parts. In addition, this text is over a carousel slider of images. The error looks as such:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZSFL.png

My goal is to crop the page's width where the element overextends at. This is my code:

`

```
#title-display{
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     margin: -40px 0 0 -450px;
}
#title-display span{
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

#title-display h1 {
     display: inline;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-width: 8px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 4vw;
}
```

`

I use margin: -40px 0 0 -450px; to center the text.

Here is some html in case:

```
<div id="title-display">
                <span>
                     <h1><strong>Adrian's Workflow<strong></h1>
                     <p class="kicker">Designer // Programmer // Youtuber</p>
                </span>
           </div>
```

Comment: uhm.. Why not just `text-align:center;` the title rather than margining the hell out of it?

Comment: That forces it out of view so I added the margin.

Comment: Can you provide some html?

Comment: #title-display should have the property `overflow: hidden;` not the span. and just aside, you really shouldn't do it that way, consider doing it the proper css way

Comment: I added html and I did try overflow:hidden. I stated that in my original post. It failed to work and I don't know why hence I used margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could position the `#title-display` element at 50%, 50% then use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to offset it by half its width and height regardless of its actual size. Like so.

```css
body {background:#666;}
#title-display{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align:center;
}

#title-display h1 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-width: 8px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-color: white;
     padding: 10px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 4vw;
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<header id="title-display">
    <h1><strong>Adrian's Workflow</strong></h1>
    <p class="kicker">Designer // Programmer // Youtuber</p>
</header>
```

Comment: I prefer your answer therefore deleted mine and +1'ed you :)

Comment: I didn't require the translate actually. white-space: nowrap on the h1 fixed everything. Thank you!